# How to solve ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I have a sliding menu application and a wanted to add a new block of items. I have added it but when I run my application it crashes and the log shows this error, and I can't figure out why. Thanks a lot !!!

Here is my:
**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.cngcnasaud.orar;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private CustomActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] menuItems;


    private static final String TAG = "AudioDemo";
    private static final String isPlaying = "Media is Playing"; 
    private static final String notPlaying = "Media has stopped Playing"; 


    MediaPlayer player;
    Button playerButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gc);

        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping

        // Get the button from the view
        playerButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonmp);
        playerButton.setText(R.string.play_label);
        playerButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        playerButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);












        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        _initMenu();
        mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }





        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + v);
            if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonmp) {
                playPause();
            }

    }




    private void demoPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        player.pause();
        playerButton.setText(R.string.play_label);

        Log.d(TAG, notPlaying);
}

    private void playPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(player.isPlaying()) {
          demoPause();
        } else {
          demoPlay();
        }   
    }

    private void demoPlay() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        player.start();
        playerButton.setText(R.string.stop_label);

        Log.d(TAG, isPlaying);
}




    private void _initMenu() {
        NsMenuAdapter mAdapter = new NsMenuAdapter(this);

        // Add Header
        mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header);

        // Add first block

        menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items);
        String[] menuItemsIcon = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items_icon);

        int res = 0;
        for (String item : menuItems) {

            int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string",
                    this.getPackageName());
            int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon[res],
                    "drawable", this.getPackageName());

            NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
            if (res==1) mItem.counter=0; //it is just an example...
            if (res==3) mItem.counter=0; //it is just an example...
            mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
            res++;
        }

        mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header2);

        menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items2);
        String[] menuItemsIcon1 = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items_icon2);

        int res2 = 0;
        for (String item : menuItems) {

            int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string",
                    this.getPackageName());
            int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon1[res2],
                    "drawable", this.getPackageName());

            NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
            if (res2==1) mItem.counter=0; //it is just an example...
            mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
            res2++;
        }

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        if (mDrawerList != null)
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        /*
         * The action bar home/up should open or close the drawer.
         * ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
         */
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle your other action bar items...
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

        public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout){
            super(
                mActivity,
                mDrawerLayout, 
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.ns_menu_open, 
                R.string.ns_menu_close);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_close));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_open));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);         
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            if (position == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Istoric.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                mDrawer.closeDrawers();
            }
            else if (position == 2) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Academicieni.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                mDrawer.closeDrawers();
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profesori.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                mDrawer.closeDrawers();
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                Intent intent4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Elevi.class);
                startActivity(intent4);
                mDrawer.closeDrawers();
            }

            if (position == 5) {
                Intent intent5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowImageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent5);
                mDrawer.closeDrawers();
            }
            if (position == 6) {
                Intent intent6 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Medii.class);
                startActivity(intent6);
                mDrawer.closeDrawers();
            }
            if (position == 7) {
                Intent intent7 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Despre.class);
                startActivity(intent7);
                mDrawer.closeDrawers();
            }
            if (position == 8) {
                Intent intent8 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Feedback.class);
                startActivity(intent8);
                mDrawer.closeDrawers();
            }

        }



    }
        }
```

**Logcat**

```
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cngcnasaud.orar/com.cngcnasaud.orar.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.cngcnasaud.orar.MainActivity._initMenu(MainActivity.java:160)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at com.cngcnasaud.orar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-18 20:44:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1273):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks !!!

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="ns_menu_items">
        <item>ns_menu_snippet1</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet2</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet3</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet4</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet5</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet6</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="ns_menu_items2">
        <item>ns_menu_snippet21</item>
        <item>ns_menu_snippet22</item>
    </string-array>





    <array name="ns_menu_items_icon">
        <item>istorici</item>
        <item>academicienii</item>
        <item>orari</item>
        <item>orari</item>
        <item>orari</item>
        <item>orari</item>
    </array>


        <array name="ns_menu_items_icon2">
        <item>desprei</item>
        <item>feedbacki</item>
    </array>








    <array name="ns_menu_items_icon2">
        <item>ic_action_settings</item>

    </array>

</resources>
```

Comment: com.cngcnasaud.orar.MainActivity._initMenu(MainActivity.java:160) -- line 160 of MainActivity?

Comment: `int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon2[res2],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that

```
String[] menuItemsIcon2 = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items_icon2);

int res2 = 0;
for (String item : menuItems) {
```

should be

```
String[] menuItemsIcon2 = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items_icon2);

int res2 = 0;
for (String item : menuItemsIcon2) {
```

In your second for each loop, you want to loop through the items of the `menuItemsIcon2` array, and it seems that `menuItems` have more elements that `menuItemsIcon2`.

Since you're incrementing `res2` at each iteration, you go out of the bounds of `menuItemsIcon2`.

Comment: No.. still persisting.

Comment: @user3348368 Could you post the updated code with the stacktrace?

Comment: It's the same code posted in the first post, I deleted the 2nd block of items and tried to add it again, but still no chance to work.

Comment: @user3348368 That would be still cool if you can update the new code without this block and the new stacktrace.

Comment: I tried something else. If I use the first block of items' array, it's working, but when I change the array, it's crashing. A few days ago, I made another app with the same sliding and 3 blocks of items and worked just perfect, but now, the same code, it's not working anymore. How to explain that? I've spend the whole day trying to figure, it's pissing me off. Thanks for the help..

Comment: @user3348368 Without your code, that will be hard to help... Is it the same error? If yes check the length of both arrays.

Comment: Yes. It's the same error. The length of the first is 5 and the length of the 2nd is 2.

Comment: @user3348368 But you are incrementing `res` at each iteration. So at some point `res` is >= 2 and you go out of bounds.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean.. how to descrease the res then if it's >= 2?

Comment: @user3348368 Please just show your new code as it's hard to explain what you're actually doing and what appends. It seems like you were incrementing `res` at each iteration. Since the ``menuItems` array have more elements than the `menuItemsIcon` array, the `res` variable is keeping incremented and then you go out of the bounds when trying to access an element in the `menuItemsIcon` array.

Comment: I've edited the first post with the exact MainActivity I have and this is the lane where I get the error:   `int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon1[res2],`    . The logcat are posted too in the first post. Thanks !

Comment: @user3348368 Does `menuItemsIcon1` have the same length of `menuItems` (when you get your array from `menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ns_menu_items2);`? Do you understand what an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is?

Comment: What I understand.. menuItems gets the array from ns_menu_items2 which contains 2 items. Then, menuItemsIcon1 gets the array from ns_menu_items2 which has 2 items, same as ns_menu_items2. What I don't understand is why menuItems does not need to be changed and menuItemsIcon have to be changed. I mean, why do menuItemsIcon need to have that 1 at the end and menuItems don't? .. I posted my array.xml to understand exactly the procces. Thanks!

Comment: @user3348368 In your xml file you have 2 `<array name="ns_menu_items_icon2">`, one with one item and one with two.

Comment: Omg.. Can I be that stupid? I'm ashamed now. I'm so sorry for the time wasted. I had some bad days and I had to finish this app and looked like my attention was somewhere far away. I'm so sorry !

Comment: @user3348368 No problems. Cool the problem is fixed :) Btw did this compiled? It shouldn't IMO

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have same number of elements in menuitems and iconmenuitems. That is the possible source of error.

Comment: I've posted the array.xml to see exactly. Thanks !

Comment: Did you notice there are two ns_menu_items_icon2 arrays ? One with 2 items and another with 1 item. Accept the answer if it is fixed !